# Why does a subroutine with an array as an input give faster performance than the same subroutine with an automatic local array?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am re-writing some legacy code to improve readability and hopefully make it easier to maintain.

I am trying to decrease the number of input parameters for the subroutines, but I found that changing
`subroutine sub(N, ID)` --> `subroutine sub(N)`
had noticeably reduced performance.

`ID` is only used in `sub`, so I don't believe it makes sense to have it as an input.
Is it possible to use `sub(N)` without taking the performance hit?
(For my uses, N < 10, where the performance is 5-10x worse.)

Performance comparisons:

1. `sub_1`

   - `N = 4`, 0.9 seconds
   - `N = 20`, 1.0 seconds
   - `N = 200`, 2.1 seconds
2. `sub_2`

   - `N = 4`, 0.07 seconds
   - `N = 20`, 0.18 seconds
   - `N = 200`, 1.3 seconds

I am using Mac OS 10.14.6 with gfortran 5.2.0

```
program test
  integer, parameter  :: N = 1
  real, dimension(N)  :: ID


  call CPU_time(t1)

  do i = 1, 10000000
    CALL sub_1(N)
  end do

  call CPU_time(t2)
  write ( *, * ) 'Elapsed real time =', t2 - t1



  call CPU_time(t1)

  do i = 1, 10000000
    CALL sub_2(N, ID)
  end do

  call CPU_time(t2)
  write ( *, * ) 'Elapsed real time =', t2 - t1

end program test



SUBROUTINE sub_1(N)
  integer,            intent(in)      :: N
  real, dimension(N)                  :: ID

  ID = 0.0

END SUBROUTINE sub_1



SUBROUTINE sub_2(N, ID)
  integer,            intent(in)      :: N
  real, dimension(N), intent(in out)  :: ID

  ID = 0.0

END SUBROUTINE sub_2
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you compiled it, please?

Comment: It would also be useful to have the times in the quest8n rather than the code, I almost missed them

Comment: @IanBush Perhaps this is naive, but I just used the command `gfortran test.f95` then executed with `./a.out` (in the terminal)

Comment: Thanks! Please add the -O3 flag to the compile line and repeat.

Comment: You can also explicitly add the `-fstack-arrays` option.

Comment: @IanBush, using `gfortran -O3 test.f95` significantly decreased the runtime for `sub_2` (1e-6 seconds), but `sub_1` stayed at about 1 second for all values of N

Comment: @francescalus, `gfortran -O3 -fstack-arrays` significantly decreased the run times for both `sub_1` and `sub_2`, but `sub_2` still seems to be orders of magnitude faster than `sub_1` (~1000x)

Comment: You really should print the result at the end of each computation, but after calling `cpu_time()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a "feature" of the old version of gfortran you are using. If I use later versions at least for N=10 the times are much more comparable:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ head s.f90
program test
  integer, parameter  :: N = 10
  real, dimension(N)  :: ID


  call CPU_time(t1)

  do i = 1, 10000000
    CALL sub_1(N)
  end do
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-5 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

GNU Fortran comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Fortran
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-5 -O3 s.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Elapsed real time =  0.149489999    
 Elapsed real time =   1.99675560E-06
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-6 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-6 -O3 s.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Elapsed real time =   7.00005330E-06
 Elapsed real time =   5.00003807E-06
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-7 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-7 -O3 s.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Elapsed real time =   8.00006092E-06
 Elapsed real time =   6.00004569E-06
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-8 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran-8 -O3 s.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Elapsed real time =   9.00030136E-06
 Elapsed real time =   6.00004569E-06
```

However I would take all the above with a bucket-full of salt. It is more than likely the optimiser has worked out that it doesn't actually need to do anything in this simple case and so has just got rid of all the operations you want to time - the only benchmark that can actually tell you about this is the code you want to run.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling it might be a version issue. I will update. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @NickBrady please see the extra comments on compiler optimisation I have just added ...

Comment: The possibility of the optimizer is a very likely problem. Some thoughts wouldn't it be better to to have the subroutines in a separate file (so the compiler has less  chance to inline) and also add an output argument that gets a value that is in the loop e.g. added to a program variable (and don't forget to write it as otherwise the compiler optimizer might be clever again ...). Unfortunately I cannot test these ideas as I only have one compiler version.

Answer (score 1):

`sub_1` and `sub_2` aren't really comparable. In `sub_1` you are allocating `ID`, initializing all of the elements and then throwing it away when the subroutine returns (because it is local to the subroutine).

Since that `ID` array is never used, the compiler can optimize away the creation and initialization of it. That's what gfortran does if you compile with -O3. The generated code for `sub_1` does nothing but return.

In `sub_2` it still has to set all of the elements of `ID` to 0.0.

Comment: With this theory, does it make sense that `sub_2` is the faster subroutine?

Comment: Without optimization `sub_2` is likely to be faster because it doesn't have to allocate the array.
With optimization I would expect `sub_1` to be faster.
But the bigger point is that they aren't comparable because they don't accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The compiler can throw out either result, it is never printed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it has to do with array allocation.

The process of allocating memory itself takes time. When you pass the array unaltered into the subroutine `sub_2`, I think it's very likely that the subroutine does not need to allocate memory for the array. This might assume that the arrays are created on the heap, not the stack, but I'm not 100% certain.

On the other hand, for the subroutine `sub_1`, it needs to allocate the space for the array every time anew.

I'm unfortunately not too well versed in optimisation, so I hope that other people will agree with me or tell me that I'm wrong ;)