# Why does a subroutine with an array from a "use module" statement give faster performance than the same subroutine a locally sized array?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938113/why-does-a-subroutine-with-an-array-as-an-input-give-faster-performance-than-the), but I believe the issue is more clearly identified with this example.

I have some legacy code that looks like this:

```
subroutine ID_OG(N, DETERM)
  use variables, only: ID
  implicit real (A-H,O-Z)
  implicit integer(I-N)

  DETERM = 1.0
  DO 1 I=1,N
1       ID(I)=0
  DETERM = sum(ID)
end subroutine ID_OG
```

Replacing `use variables, only: ID` with `real, dimension(N) :: ID` or `real, dimension(:), allocatable :: ID` causes a noticeable performance loss. Why is this? Is this expected behavior? I am wondering if it has something to do with the program needing to repeatedly allocate memory for the local array `ID`, while the `use` statement allows the program to skip the memory allocation step.

In the legacy code `ID` is in `module variables` but it is only used within the subroutine `ID_OG`. It is not used anywhere else in the code - it is not an input or an output. To me, it seems like good programming practice for `ID` to be removed from `module variables` and defined locally in the subroutine. But perhaps that isn't the case.

[image]

Minimum working example (MWE):
compiling as `gfortran -O3 test.f95` using gfortran 8.2.0

```
MODULE variables
  implicit none

  real, dimension(:),   allocatable :: ID

END MODULE variables


program test
  use variables

  implicit none

  integer             :: N
  integer             :: loop_max = 1e6
  integer             :: ii                    ! loop index
  real                :: DETERM

  real :: t1, t2
  real :: t_ID_OG, t_ID_header, t_ID_no_ID, t_OG_no_ID, t_allocate

  character(*), parameter :: format_header = '((A5, 1X), 20(A12,1X))'
  character(*), parameter :: format_data = '((I5, 1X), 20(ES12.5, 1X))'

  open(1, file = 'TimingSubroutines_ID.txt', status = 'unknown')
  write(1,format_header) 'N', 't_Legacy', 't_header', 't_head_No_ID', 't_Leg_no_ID', &
                            & 't_allocate'

  do N = 1, 100

    allocate(ID(N))


    call CPU_time(t1)
    do ii = 1, loop_max
      CALL ID_OG(N, DETERM)
    end do
    call CPU_time(t2)
    t_ID_OG = t2 - t1
    print*, N, DETERM


    call CPU_time(t1)
    do ii = 1, loop_max
      CALL ID_header(N, DETERM)
    end do
    call CPU_time(t2)
    t_ID_header = t2 - t1
    print*, N, DETERM


    call CPU_time(t1)
    do ii = 1, loop_max
      CALL ID_header_no_ID(N, DETERM)
    end do
    call CPU_time(t2)
    t_ID_no_ID = t2 - t1
    print*, N, DETERM


    call CPU_time(t1)
    do ii = 1, loop_max
      CALL ID_OG_no_ID(N, DETERM)
    end do
    call CPU_time(t2)
    t_OG_no_ID = t2 - t1
    print*, N, DETERM


    call CPU_time(t1)
    do ii = 1, loop_max
      CALL ID_OG_allocate(N, DETERM)
    end do
    call CPU_time(t2)
    t_allocate = t2 - t1
    print*, N, DETERM


    deallocate(ID)
    write(1,format_data) N, t_ID_OG, t_ID_header, t_ID_no_ID, t_OG_no_ID, t_allocate

  end do



end program test


subroutine ID_OG(N, DETERM)
  use variables, only: ID
  implicit real (A-H,O-Z)
  implicit integer(I-N)


  DETERM = 1.0
  DO 1 I=1,N
1       ID(I)=0
  DETERM = sum(ID)

end subroutine ID_OG



subroutine ID_header(N, DETERM)
  use variables, only: ID
  implicit none

  integer, intent(in)  :: N
  real,    intent(out) :: DETERM
  integer              :: I


  DETERM = 1.0
  DO 1 I=1,N
1       ID(I)=0
  DETERM = sum(ID)

end subroutine ID_header



subroutine ID_header_no_ID(N, DETERM)
  implicit none

  integer, intent(in)  :: N
  real,    intent(out) :: DETERM
  integer              :: I
  real, dimension(N)   :: ID


  DETERM = 1.0
  DO 1 I=1,N
1       ID(I)=0
  DETERM = sum(ID)

end subroutine ID_header_no_ID


subroutine ID_OG_no_ID(N, DETERM)
  implicit real (A-H,O-Z)
  implicit integer(I-N)
  real, dimension(N)   :: ID


  DETERM = 1.0
  DO 1 I=1,N
1       ID(I)=0
  DETERM = sum(ID)

end subroutine ID_OG_no_ID


subroutine ID_OG_allocate(N, DETERM)
  implicit real (A-H,O-Z)
  implicit integer(I-N)
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: ID

  allocate(ID(N))


  DETERM = 1.0
  DO 1 I=1,N
1       ID(I)=0
  DETERM = sum(ID)

end subroutine ID_OG_allocate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocating the arrays takes time. The compiler is free to allocate the local arrays where-ever it wants, but it can typically be adjusted by compiler-specific flags. Use `-fstack-arrays` for gfortran to force local arrays to stack.

Allocating on the stack is just changing the stack pointer, it is virtually for free. Allocating on the heap, however, is more involved and requires some bookkeeping.

There are situations where local variables are in order and there are situations where global (module) variables are in order. One can also use local saved variables or variables that are components of some objects. **One cannot say which one is better without seeing the complete design of the code in question.**

FWIW, with `-fstack-arrays` I do not see much difference except when allocating explicitly using `allocate()`:

[image]

Explicit `allocate` will always use the heap.

Without `-fstack-arrays` I do see some:

[image]

The graphs are quite noisy because my notebook is running many processes at the same time.

---

This is not to say that one should always use `-fstack-arrays`, I used to demonstrate the difference. The option is useful, but care must be taken to avoid a stack overflow error. `-fmax-stack-var-size` may help with that.

Comment: This is very useful thank you. I too see similar performance between `use variables` and `real, dimension(N) :: ID`. I noticed that your plots only have 4 datasets, while mine had a 5th using `real, dimension(:), allocatable :: ID`. I noticed that this version still has worse performance with the flag `-fstack-arrays`. Is that what you see as well?

Comment: @NickBrady Yes, if you explicitly allocate, it will always go to heap, there is no other way. Well, theoretically the compiler could do some lifetime static analysis, but it is unlikely to ever be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

As your tests are pointing out, the additional overhead of all methods which do not use the `module` variable is due to the language's phylosophy to not bother the user with memory handling too much.

The compiler will decide where memory should be allocated, unless you start tinkering with compiler flags. You see allocation/freeing time as a drawback, but your analysis also shows:

- stack vs. heap memory handling overhead quickly gets smaller and smaller: for `N>=100`, it is already <50%. a `dimension(100)` array is a ridiculously small memory chunk on a modern computer.
- declaring a variable in a module just for speeding up storage is a `Fortran 90` way of making it a global, and as such, it is a deprecated coding style.

I think the best strategy to make the code well-coded *and* fast is:

- Is `N` going to be constant through the whole runtime? Then, it would be a good idea to encapsulate it into a class:

```
module myCalculation
    implicit none

    type, public: fancyMethod
        integer :: N = 0
        real, allocatable :: ID(:)

    contains
       
        procedure :: init 
        procedure :: compute
        procedure :: is_init
             
    end type fancyMethod

contains

    elemental subroutine init(self,n)
        class(fancyMethod), intent(inout) :: self
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real, allocatable :: tmp(:)

        self%N = n
        allocate(tmp(N)); tmp(:) = 0
        call move_alloc(from=tmp,to=self%ID)
    end subroutine init

    elemental logical function is_init(self) 
        class(fancyMethod), intent(in) :: self
        is_init = allocated(self%ID) .and. size(self%ID)>0
    end function is_init

    real function compute(self,n,...) result(DETERM)
        class(fancyMethod), intent(inout) :: self
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        ....

        if (.not.is_init(self)) call init(self,N)
 
        DETERM = sum(self%ID(1:N)) 
    end function compute

end module myCalculation
```

- Is `N` going to be constant and small? Why not just use a `PARAMETER` to define its max size? if it is a parameter, the compiler will perhaps always put the automatic array on the stack:

```
real function computeWithMaxSize(N) result(DETERM)
    integer, intent(in) :: N
    integer, parameter :: MAX_SIZE = 1024
    real :: ID(MAX_SIZE)

    [...]

    if (N>MAX_SIZE) stop ' N is too large! '

    DETERM = sum(ID(1:N))
end function computeWithMaxSize
```

- Is `N` going to be variable-sized *and* large? Then, the in-routine memory handling is fine, and its overhead is likely negligible, because the CPU time will be dominated by the calculation; use an `allocatable` version if you're not sure that the size can be so large to cause any stack issues:

```
real function computeWithAllocatable(N) result(DETERM)
    integer, intent(in) :: N
    real, allocatable :: ID(:)

    allocate(ID(N))
 
    [...]

    DETERM = sum(ID(1:N))
end function computeWithAllocatable
```

Comment: N will be small (<10) for the most part and either be constant or have 2 values. It is unclear to me why one would choose `module myCalculation` over something like `module var_ID real, dimension(N) :: ID`. What is the advantage for a class in this scenario?

Comment: With a class you keep high execution speed while getting the advantages of object-oriented programming: thread safety (you can allocate as many independent instances of your method as you like), and you have control that somewhere else in your code data in `ID` does not get accidentally overwritten/changed